# Shiny server - how to install packages in localhost?

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny

I have installed Shiny Server in my local machine following the steps [here](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/).

I also manage to get the default sample app running at http://127.0.0.1:3838/sample-apps/hello/

But when I want to run the app that I have been working on RStduio, I get this error,

> An error has occurred
>
> The application failed to start.
>
> The application exited during initialization.
>
> Error in library(plyr) : there is no package called ‘plyr’ Calls:
>   runApp ... sourceUTF8 -> eval -> eval -> ..stacktraceon.. -> library
>   Execution halted

I have installed all the packages via RStudio and they are in this directory,

```
/home/tealou/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/
```

I can see plyr is already installed.

```
.../3.2/
      plyr/
```

But why the Shiny Server does not pick up the packages in the directory above?

Where should I install the packages for the server then? and how?

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;
    PATH=/home/tealou/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does you `shiny-server.conf` file knows where to look for R installation in your system?

Please, read this:

> Shiny Server expects that R is available as an executable named R and
>   is in the PATH of the user which you run shiny-server as. Note that on
>   some CentOS systems, the PATH will be overridden by the startup script
>   to /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin. On such systems, if R is not
>   available in one of these locations (regardless of the user's PATH),
>   you'll need to adjust the startup script.
>
> To allow Shiny Server to search for R in additional locations, you'll
>   alter the file in /etc/init.d/shiny-server or
>   /etc/init/shiny-server.conf depending on which startup system you're
>   using (as discussed in Stopping and Starting. You can either adjust
>   the PATH variable to include the directory where R will be found, or
>   you can set an environment variable named R to tell Shiny Server
>   exactly where it should look for the executable.
>
> If you choose to adjust the PATH, you can add the directory in which
>   the executable named R is found to the line that defines the PATH
>   environment variable (PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin).

and more is available here: https://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/latest/#configuration-settings

And one obvious question just in case: you have `library(plyr)` in your code, right?

Comment: thanks for the answer. `you have library(plyr) in your code, right?` yes I have it in my code.

Comment: `PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin` I have come across this part but I don't understand what sbin: and bin: are. Do I have to replace them with something else? For instance, do you mean to add `PATH=/home/tealou/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/` in `shiny-server.conf`? Please see my edit above. But it doesn't work anyway. Rstudio does very poor documentation on this...

Answer (score 0):

As shiny-server runs on a `shiny`user the best way to provide any package is to install it for all users by:

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages(c('plyr'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```

By this solution you don´t need to make any changes on your conf files.