# Shiny user permissions for non-R executable (g++)

Tags: r, ubuntu, shiny, permissions

### Question

I am running Ubuntu 18.04, and I'm wondering what is the safest way to give an individual user access to `g++`. The user, in my case, is called `shiny`, because I am trying to host an app on my server.

I've seen answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476154/how-do-i-grant-root-access-to-a-user-application), but I'm not sure if there are other implications in this situation here.

Questions about the `shiny` user seem to be popular (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38184396/shiny-server-user-usergroup), [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35112532/shiny-server-how-to-install-packages-in-localhost)), but I don't believe these apply to my specific question.

### Information about my situation

I'm not sure I understand the [`run_as`](https://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#run_as) portion of the shiny server config file `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf`. I have a shiny app that works on my local machine, but I'm having some difficulty hosting it on my server using https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/blob/master/README.md

I am using the default configuration, so the top of the file reads

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;
```

When I visit the url to test out my app, the web browser reads

> An error has occurred
>
> The application failed to start.
>
> The application exited during initialization.

So I check the log file `/var/log/shiny-server/myapp-shiny-20200611-180231-34359.log`, and I see a linker error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhmc-lib
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sourceCpp_2.so] Error 1
Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp("do_comps.cpp", verbose = T, rebuild = T) : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
Calls: runApp ... sourceUTF8 -> eval -> eval -> ..stacktraceon.. -> <Anonymous>

WARNING: The tools required to build C++ code for R were not found.

Please install GNU development tools including a C++ compiler.

Execution halted
```

Weird, because all of this already built successfully and ran fine when I test it in a more friendly setting, running everything as root.